# When to use parameters in a Restful URL

Tags: rest, restful-url, url-parameters

I'm trying to find the best way to make a restful URL when I need to use some complex parameters.

In my original design I needed to create a setting and I used this URL to go to the form to create the new setting:

```
GET /setting/new
```

Right now I've introduced settingcategories (1 settingcategory contains multiple settings) and I'm searching for the best way to go to the settingsform using the REST principle.

Some possible solutions:

```
//using a parameter
    GET /setting/new?settingcategory=5152ebabf1f7b6134b000007
//include the settingcategory in the URL
    GET /settingcategory/5152ebabf1f7b6134b000007/setting/new
//using bad Restful design and use a POST to display the form
//and put the settingcategory in the body of the POST
    POST /setting/new
```

I'm pretty new to REST but at the moment the second option seems the most logical to me.

Comment: I liked this tutorial on designing REST API's: https://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid using the parameter in query string like "?settincategory=..."

You can do like in your second option, it would be cleaner to have :

> `/settingcategories/5152ebabf1f7b6134b000007/setting/new`